# Partially synchronous model in broadcast

Tags: multiparty-computation, broadcast-encryption

I am confused by the different definitions attributed to partially synchronous model: for e.g., in a [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1073814.1073878) by Hevia and Micciancio (PODC 2005), they state that messages sent in one round are guaranteed to be delivered in the next round, but this is completely different from the (original) [definition](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/42282.42283) put forth by Dwork, Lynch and Stockmeyer (JACM 1988) (has multiple, equivalent definitions: GST model and unkown $\Delta$ model).

Comment: It seems, in the mentioned paper the authors have defined what the round means. In section 3.1 we have, "The network is partially synchronous, which means parties have perfectly synchronized clocks which “tick” at discrete instants. The time interval between the $i$-th tick and the $(i + 1)$-th tick is called the ***$i$-th round***".